# Live Update Callback -> afterTitle with Array via JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, chart.js

I'm working on a chart, I'm live updating the Chart every 5 seconds that the data comes in. I could manage to get the info from the database and update it really easy, but I just came across a problem with involves setting a path to a part of the chart, in the case: options->tootltips->callbacks->afterTitle and inside of it create an array and pass the array from the JSON to an array inside the callback.
What I would need to do, In a really brief way is, since I already made a function to update the info from my Data and Labels, somehow I will need to make **inside this** **function**, a path to the afterTitle, than I will be able send the fifth array, in with stores the data. As you can see in my function, I could manage to do it for the data and label. 
I **can't** have another function that updates, so basically I can't have 2 **loadData()**, because it makes the Chart blink every time it updates, and that's not what I'm aiming for (The chart can't blink).

Inside this patch, I made an example that didn't work, with is the //:

```
$.getJSON('loadchart.php', function(response) {
          myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data = response[0];
          myLineChart.data.datasets[1].data = response[1];
          myLineChart.data.datasets[2].data = response[2];
          myLineChart.data.datasets[3].data = response[3];
          myLineChart.data.labels = response[4];

          //The response array that I need is response[5];
          //myLineChart.options.tooltips.callbacks[1] = return response[tooltipItem[0]['index']]; 
          myLineChart.update();
        });
```

All my Chart so you can see the path:

```
 <script>

    function loadData() {
      $.getJSON('loadchart.php', function(response) {
        myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data = response[0];
        myLineChart.data.datasets[1].data = response[1];
        myLineChart.data.datasets[2].data = response[2];
        myLineChart.data.datasets[3].data = response[3];
        myLineChart.data.labels = response[4];

        myLineChart.update();
      });
    }

    loadData();
    setInterval(loadData, 5000);

    var lbl = [];
    var ctx1 = document.getElementById('mychart1').getContext('2d');

    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx1, {
        type: 'line', 
        data: {
          labels: lbl,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Corrente 1",
              data: [],
              borderWidht: 6,
              borderColor: 'red',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
            {
              label: "Corrente 2",
              data: [],
              borderWidht: 6,
              borderColor: 'blue',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
            {
              label: "Corrente 3",
              data: [],
              borderWidht: 6,
              borderColor: 'green',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
            {
              label: "Corrente Total",
              data: [],
              borderWidht: 6,
              borderColor: 'black',
              backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            },
          ]            
        },
        options: {
          animation:{
            update: 0
          },
          scales: {
            yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
              }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
              gridLines: {
                display: false
              }
            }]
          },

          title: {
            display: true,
            fontSize: 20,
            text: "Gráfico das Correntes"
          },

          labels: {
            fontStyle: "bold",
          },

          layout: {
            padding: {
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0
            }
          },
          tooltips: {
            enabled: true,
            mode: 'single',
            responsive: true,
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            titleFontFamily: "'Arial'",
            titleFontSize: 14,
            titleFontStyle: 'bold',
            titleAlign: 'center',
            titleSpacing: 4,
            titleMarginBottom: 10,
            bodyFontFamily: "'Mukta'",
            bodyFontSize: 14,
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderColor: 'grey',
            callbacks:{
              title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                  return data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index];
              },
              afterTitle: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                var tempo = [];
                return tempo[tooltipItem[0]['index']];
              },
              label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';                  
                    if (label) {
                        label += ': ';
                    }
                    label += (tooltipItem.yLabel)+"A";                  
                    return label;
              }
            }
          },
          aspectRatio: 1,
          maintainAspectRatio: false
        }
    });
</script>
```

The part I need is this one:

```
afterTitle: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                var tempo = [];
                return tempo[tooltipItem[0]['index']];
```

Comment: Your response "5" would require that you get or create a data array with so much entrys. You just has 4. myLineChart.options.tooltips.callbacks[1] will not work cause this is a Object, you use the syntax for a array. So i would suggest to check out your php to produce the data structure you need. JSON Donkey Bridge [I AM A ARRAY] {i am a object}.

Comment: The problem is, how I'm going to update this data every 5000 seconds, I already created all of the path, etc, would be easier if I found a way from there

Comment: I would need to update this array, and send it when I have a chart.update()

Answer (score 0):

This will display a clock but you can also set it to 5000 seconds and call your chart update. Which i would suggest to put in some kind of AJAX to let it work asynchonous.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <script>
            function startTime() {
              var today = new Date();
              var h = today.getHours();
              var m = today.getMinutes();
              var s = today.getSeconds();
              m = checkTime(m);
              s = checkTime(s);
              document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
              h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
              var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);  //<----  !!!
            }
            function checkTime(i) {
              if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
              return i;
            }
            </script>
            </head>

            <body onload="startTime()">

            <div id="txt"></div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: I don't get how could I implement this in my chart. I would need to get the info from my database If you could make an example with the database data. I can't have 2 timeouts in my chart, because it makes the Chart blink.

Comment: Then you will have to wait til monday, this rest week i will not have enough time to play with. The idea is riughly to use a timer to start as ajax routine all 5000 seconds which will then update the chart by its callback. There will be no flicker . Its javascript. You update the html without reloading the page.

Comment: If you could help me on Monday I would appreciate it a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you mention in `afterTitle` function you want to create an array and pass the array from the JSON to an array inside the callback, and the missing part is you are creating an array `tempo` and treating it like an object `tempo[tooltipItem[0]['index']];`, but what you need to do is push this object `tooltipItem[0]['index']` to `tempo` array.

Please replace `afterTitle` function with the below code

```
afterTitle: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            var tempo = [];
            return tempo.push(tooltipItem[0]['index']);
```

Comment: Well, But how will the tempo[] receive values if I'm not inserting them anywhere in my code? Where should I put the tempo array? inside the JSON File? Could you try to explain it a bit better